# Tensorflow root directory in Mac

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to use the `transform_graph` in Tensorflow. However, according to [TensorFlow: Quantization Error "Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:transform_graph' failed; build aborted."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065555/tensorflow-quantization-error-analysis-of-target-tensorflow-tools-graph-tra), I still need to configure tensorflow by issuing `./configure` in the top root Tensorflow directory:

```
$ cd tensorflow  # cd to the top-level directory created
$ ./configure
```

Where is the top-level directory of Tensorflow?

I did this:

```
C:\> python
>>>import tensorflow as tf
>>>print(tf.__file__ )
```

And found out that my tensorflow directory is in `/Users/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow`.

However, when I issue the `./configure` command inside this directory, it says

> -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

And checked that this directory does not contain any hidden file named `configure`

I checked the Tensorflow repo in Github found in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools, and found the `configure` file. I compared the `tensorflow` folder from Github and in my local machine and found out that they don't contain the same files. Am I in the wrong directory in my local machine? What Tensorflow root directory is referred here?

Answer (score 0):

use the following to find the location:

```
pip3 show tensorflow
```

or

```
pip show tensorflow
```

Output on my MAC OS:

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.12.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages
Requires: six, absl-py, keras-preprocessing, tensorboard, astor, protobuf, 
numpy, gast, termcolor, grpcio, wheel, keras-applications
Required-by:
```

Refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVS3U1OQzO4